# Download the images links facebook group post

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I have made a code using selenium to login Facebook and I am trying to get all the links for the images to a specific post in a group

```
Sub Facebook()
    Dim bot As New WebDriver
    With bot
        .AddArgument "--disable-notifications"
        .Start "Chrome", "https://www.facebook.com"
        .Get "/"
        .FindElementById("email").SendKeys "email"
        .FindElementById("pass").SendKeys "pass"
        .FindElementById("u_0_b").Click
        .Wait 5000
        .Get "https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=2776252612695761&id=2341556939498666"
        '.FindElementByClass("l9j0dhe7").Click
        .Wait 5000
        
    End With
    Stop
End Sub
```

I tried to find any clue but I am lost and can't find a start point as for fetching the links.
To simplify the issue, this is a post on a group and the post has about 66 images that I need to bring the links of those images.

Comment: Are you sure that the locators are stable? I know that FB is using dynamic locators.

Comment: I am not sure. I am asking to make sure if it is possible or I have to get rid of this idea.

Comment: I'll post the workaround as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of going to that page where are the picture, you can navigate straight to the first photo from the album. (I won't post the url because is too long)

From there, proceed with the following:

1. Get the link from this locator:

   WebElement image = driver.findElement(By.xpath("**//div[@data-pagelet='MediaViewerPhoto']/div/img**"));

   String link = image.getAttribute("src");
2. Navigate to the next image by clicking on next button:

   `//div[@aria-label='Next photo' and @role='button']`

aand continue to scrape the link.

You can add your code into a while loop and do it until next button is visible (when you will reach the last image, the button won't be available).
Also, add a wait before navigating to next image to make sure that is properly loaded.